# How can i authenticate username and password with ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, arraylist

I'm trying to do Login application with Java Swing and I'm having some problem with authenticating username and passwords with ArrayList . I didn't figure it out if I need to use boolean to return true value when username and password are correct or showing some message. Can you help me building the class to authenticating users ?

Here are my codes.

> kAd means Username,kSifre means password.Others getters and setters and kullanicilar means users

```
public class kullanicilar {
private int kId;
private String kAd;
private String kSifre;

public kullanicilar(int kId,String kAd,String kSifre){
    this.kId=kId;
    this.kAd=kAd;
    this.kSifre=kSifre;
}

public int getkId() {
    return kId;
}

public void setkId(int kId) {
    this.kId = kId;
}

public String getkAd() {
    return kAd;
}

public void setkAd(String kAd) {
    this.kAd = kAd;
}

public String getkSifre() {
    return kSifre;
}

public void setkSifre(String kSifre) {
    this.kSifre = kSifre;
}}
```

And this is where I store the data

```
public class KulVeritabani {
private ArrayList<kullanicilar> Kuls = new ArrayList<>();

public KulVeritabani(){
    Kuls.add(new kullanicilar(0, "admin", "12345"));
    Kuls.add(new kullanicilar(1,"admin2","111222"));
}

public ArrayList<kullanicilar> getKuls() {
    return Kuls;
}

public void setKuls(ArrayList<kullanicilar> kuls) {
    Kuls = kuls;
}
```

I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure, but wouldn't it be better to pass the username/password to some other class which returns a `kullanicilar` if validated or `null` (or throws an exception) if not?  Otherwise, if you want to authenticate ALL the users in the `List`, you could return a `boolean` array, which is one-to-one map with the `List` indicating which users were authenticated (ie index `0` in the array is mapped to index `0` of the `List`)

Comment: Thanks , so you are saying that don't use an ArrayList and if you use you will need to map it or create an Object array or something . Can you be more clear about this. Waiting your help.